# Row Coloring in Django Template based on "ifchanged"?

Tags: python, django, templates, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table of events and I want to color them in groups by the day of the week the event happened in.

So I would want something like:

```
Grey  -> Monday    | event1
Grey  -> Monday    | event2
White -> Tuesday   | event3
Grey  -> Friday    | event4
```

I'm scratching my head looking at cycle and ifchanged, and I just don't see how it would work.  I think the only way to make it work is to contrive a temporary variable.

I COULD take the mod of weekday, but there could be a case where a day is skipped.  So really I want to alternate on an {% ifchanged %} for the day of the week.

(Using Bootstrap, btw, so feel free to utilize that.  Would rather not use JS if I can avoid it.)

Comment: Can you show the template code. I m interested in the way you are looping

Comment: Don't have the code handy now, but you can assume it is a simple loop over every event - one iteration per row.  But your question makes me realize I could do a group by day and do a nested loop.... Maybe save the cycle output with a 'with' tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give the current state of a cycle a name and then just refer to that when nothing has changed.

```
<tr style="background-color:
    {% ifchanged event.date %}
        {% cycle "grey" "white" as rowcolors %}
    {% else %}
        {{ rowcolors }}
    {% endifchanged %}">

    ...

</tr>
```

Comment: I tried something like that... I think rowcolors would still cycle every time the 'else' is hit, if what you wrote is what I tried.  But you know the docs say it is exactly what I want.  I'll try it first thing tomorrow.  Thanks!

Comment: @rrauenza the code in the answer worked for me. `rowcolors` will only cycle when the date changes. If it doesn't work for you, let me know and we can look into it.

Comment: Yes that did work.  What is confusing as well is that the {% cycle A B as foo %} also emits a value, and then I'd also convinced myself that referencing the variable also causes the cycle to turn.